# How to use odbc syntax connection string in ASP.net with SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, odbc

I already hosted my project for free using ASP.net and MySQL Server. There is a run time error happening and a friend of mine suggested to try the odbc sysntax connection string but both of us don't know how to actually use it. Please help. I badly need this for our thesis. I can't go through the system since from the log-in page, the error appears already. This is the url of the project I am talking about. lawfirminformationsystem.somee.com/SHARED/Login.aspx You may open this so that you may see the error. Kindly input "avee" as both the Username and Password and click the "Login" button". Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are using SQL server as backend, you cannot use odbc connection string,
The sql server connection string should work,  check if your connection string is correct,where you are hosting your database?
what is the error you are getting, please post the error details.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Nabeel_Bape. My subscription is actually inclusive of the database already. Below is the error 's decription and details

Comment: Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

Comment: try putting the custom error tags in your web.config file, it should look like this:
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
make sure you put this tag in system.web sections so the structure should look like this,
<configuration> 
    <system.web> 
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>  
    </system.web> 
</configuration> 
I have encountered this error before and putting this line solved the issue for me.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion sir. I already copied the error tag and pasted it in the web.config. But still there is an error:

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)